# Query a Parent-Child Tree

Tags: oracle

```
PARENT_AC            CHILD_AC
100         101
101         102
102         103
200         201
201         202
300         301
```

I need to update ACCT_TBL.PARENT_ACC_NO as below

ACCT_TBL has millions of records.
Can we use MERGE statement?

```
ACC_NO         PARENT_ACC_NO
-------------------------------
100              100
103              103
202              200
300              300
301              300
```

I need to find the root parent it may have 1 level/ 2 level/3 level or Nth level.
If I want o know parent account for 103 then My Result should be 100.

*Note: here Parent account will never be NULL*

Please help.

```
select * from (
  SELECT 
      CONNECT_BY_ROOT t1.CHILD_AC AS CHILD_AC,
      t1.CHILD_AC AS ROOT_AC,
      level AS level_ 
  FROM 
      LONSUB t1
  WHERE  1=1-- t1.PARENT_AC is null
  CONNECT BY t1.CHILD_AC = PRIOR t1.PARENT_AC
  )
  where CHILD_AC='000220245398'
 ;
```

Im using update statement to populate parent acc no to the other table (TAB1) using TEST table.

```
    update TAB1 UPD
   SET (UPD.parent_acct_no, UPD.priority_code) = ( SELECT  substr(code  ,1, instr(code, '-',1) -1) parent_ac 
                                                                            ,substr(code  , instr(code, '-',1)+1 ) priority_code
                                                                    FROM  (SELECT nvl((SELECT parent_ac||'-'|| priority_code  
                                                                                         FROM (SELECT parent_ac ,priority_code 
                                                                                                 FROM ( SELECT sub.parent_ac, src.priority_code
                                                                                                          FROM test sub , TAB1 src 
                                                                                                         WHERE sub.parent_ac  = src.V_account_number
                                                                                                           AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
                                                                                                    CONNECT BY sub.child_ac = PRIOR sub.parent_ac
                                                                                                    START WITH sub.child_ac = UPD.v_account_number
                                                                                                      ORDER BY decode(src.priority_code , 'DSC', 1, 'SC', 2, 3 ) ) T
                                                                                                WHERE 1=1
                                                                                                  AND decode(UPD.priority_code , 'DSC', 1, 'SC', 2, 3 )  > decode(T.priority_code , 'DSC', 1, 'SC', 2, 3 ) 
                                                                                                  AND ROWNUM=1) )
                                                                                        ,UPD.v_account_number||'-'||UPD.priority_code ) code
                                                                              FROM dual)
                                                                )
```

;

I'm getting following error  `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data`
but If I restrict for 100 rows update there is no error.
Also, `TAB1` will have millions of data to update.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test;

 PARENT_AC   CHILD_AC
---------- ----------
       100        101
       101        102
       102        103
       200        201
       201        202
       300        301

6 rows selected.
```

Query:

```
SQL> select parent_ac
  2  from test
  3  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  4  connect by child_ac = prior parent_ac
  5  start with child_ac = &par_child_ac;
Enter value for par_child_ac: 103

 PARENT_AC
----------
       100

SQL> /
Enter value for par_child_ac: 202

 PARENT_AC
----------
       200

SQL>
```

Comment: this par_child_ac is from updating table ACCT_TABLE

UPDATE ACCT_TABLE prnt set paretn_acc = (select parent_ac ......start with child_ac = prnt .acc_no  ) can we convert into mergestatement

Comment: I don't know. Which table is ACCT_TABLE? Which columns and data does it contain? Could you edit the original question and provide all relevant data? Because, it isn't the best idea asking one thing (which you got the answer for), and then ask something different in a comment.

Comment: Hi, Can you please suggest solution  to fix the error  while updating the table please.